# Как получить экземпляр WindowChrome для главного окна?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть совершенно стандартное WPF окно.  При вызове метода System.Windows.Shell.WindowChrome.GetWindowChrome(Window window) он каждый раз возвращает мне null. Как его использовать правильно?

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Shell;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowChrome WinChrome = WindowChrome.GetWindowChrome(this);
            if (WinChrome != null)
                MessageBox.Show(WinChrome.ResizeBorderThickness.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Вообще мне нужно свойство WindowChrome.ResizeBorderThickness для моего окна.

Comment: Перейдите вы наконец на привязки! Создайте свойство, привяжите к нему нужный вам `ResizeBorderThickness` и радуйтесь жизни. В WPF очень бредово писать дизайн через код!

Comment: Возможно я так и сделаю. Но сейчас меня интересует конкретная проблемма именно с кодом, а не с разметкой. Допустим мне  просто любопытно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень заинтересовал вопрос. Я немного с ним поковырялся и нашел решение.
Во первых у окна вы пытаетесь взять свойство которое не определено. Определить его можно в xaml разметке :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome
            ResizeBorderThickness="6"
            CaptionHeight="36"
            CornerRadius="16,16,16,16"
            GlassFrameThickness="0">
        </WindowChrome>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">CLICK</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Либо кодбехайндом. (Но я соглашусь с EvgeniyZ что надо использовать привязки и вообще активно использовать xaml)

```
public MainWindow()
{
    WindowChrome.SetWindowChrome(this, new WindowChrome()
    {
        ResizeBorderThickness = new Thickness(6, 6, 6, 6),
        CaptionHeight = 36,
        CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(16, 16, 16, 16),
        GlassFrameThickness = new Thickness(0)
    });

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Да я тоже с EvgeniyZ всей душой согласен. Но дело не в этом. Просто я думал, что у этого свойства есть некие значения по умолчанию, точнее ему присваивается некое значение сразу после создания окна. Выходит что нет? в любом случае спасибо за помощь.